# Backslash escaping in Wordpress custom posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Generatepress with Mathjax and Pods.

Backslash symbol is escaping in the custom fields.

the code to write a simple equation is

[latex]\frac { { 2 }^{ 3 } }{ \sqrt { 2 } } [/latex]

I am unable to enter backslash symbol”\” in the custom field created by PODS.

Is it a problem with WordPress, Generatepress or PODs.

Answer (score 1):

Because `\` is an escape character you have to escape it with itself so: `\\`

Comment: thank you so much.I struggled with this for hours. Your solution helped!